# secondary axis is not plotted properly

Tags: python, seaborn

When I use secondary axis, the data is not plotted by default. The secondary axis follows the order of the data in the data frame and plot as a line

```
[#matplotlib.rc_file_defaults()
# ax1 = sns.set_style(style=None, rc=None )

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

g=sns.barplot(data = df_query_date, x='utc_date', y='occurrences', alpha=0.4, color = 'green', ax=ax1)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40)

ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Occurences', color='g')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data = df_query_date, x='utc_date', y='conversion_rate', marker='o', color = 'blue', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('Conversion Rate', color='b')
plt.show()][1]
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNNdz.png)

Comment: The column `'conversion_rate'` needs to be converted from strings to numbers.

Comment: yes it works thank you!